# node.js "aes-256-gcm" in C#

Tags: c#, node.js, bouncycastle

I have the following Code in js:

```
public static decrypt(inData: Buffer, inKey: Buffer, inIv: Buffer, inAuthenticationTag: Buffer = null): Buffer
{
    const decipher: Decipher = createDecipheriv("aes-256-gcm", inKey, inIv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(inAuthenticationTag);
    return Buffer.concat([decipher.update(inData), decipher.final()]);
}
```

This code decrypts a buffer with the key and the given iv and authTag.

I tried to decrypt the same data in C# with BouncyCastle and always got the error "mac check in gcm failed"

Here is my C# Code:

```
    public static string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] authTag)
    {
        var keyParameter = new KeyParameter(key);
        var gcmParameters = new AeadParameters(
            keyParameter,
            128,
            iv);

        var gcmMode = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesFastEngine());
        gcmMode.Init(false, gcmParameters);

        var cipherBuffer = cipherText.Concat(authTag).ToArray();
        var plainBytes = new byte[gcmMode.GetOutputSize(cipherBuffer.Length)];
        var res = gcmMode.ProcessBytes(cipherBuffer, 0, cipherBuffer.Length, plainBytes, 0);
        gcmMode.DoFinal(plainBytes, res); // When executing this line i get the Exception

        var plain = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
        return plain;
    }
```

Could anyone see the mistake I did in C#?

Comment: 128 maybe should be 256?

Comment: This way it already throws at init with: "Invalid value for MAC size: 256"

Comment: Did you pass to make it work ? I face the same issue with exactly the same code, same issue in the DoFinal() call... I have no authTag in my case.